# How to do stateless aggregations in spark using Structured Streaming 2.3.0 without using flatMapsGroupWithState?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

How to do stateless aggregations in spark using Structured Streaming 2.3.0 without using flatMapsGroupWithState or Dstream API? looking for a more declarative way

Example:

```sql
select count(*) from some_view
```

I want the output to just count whatever records are available in each batch but not aggregate from the previous batch

Answer (score 1):

To do stateless aggregations in spark using Structured Streaming 2.3.0 without using `flatMapsGroupWithState` or Dstream API, you can use following code-

```
import spark.implicits._

def countValues = (_: String, it: Iterator[(String, String)]) => it.length

val query =
  dataStream
    .select(lit("a").as("newKey"), col("value"))
    .as[(String, String)]
    .groupByKey { case(newKey, _) => newKey }
    .mapGroups[Int](countValues)
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .start()
```

Here what we are doing is-

1. We added one column to our `datastream` - `newKey`. We did this so that we can do a `groupBy` over it, using `groupByKey`. I have used a literal string `"a"`, but you can use anything. Also, you need to select anyone column from the available columns in `datastream`. I have selected `value` column for this purpose, you can select anyone.
2. We created a mapping function - `countValues`, to count the values aggregated by `groupByKey` function by writing `it.length`.

So, in this way, we can count whatever records are available in each batch but not aggregating from the previous batch.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I am looking for a declarative way as stated in the questions so I am trying to solve the problem using raw sql string which implicitly means no map functions unless they can be used as part of raw SQL!

Comment: @user1870400 I am not familiar with any declarative way.

Comment: if you choose literal "a" wouldn't the entire stream becomes one group?

Comment: @user1870400 Yes, it does.

Comment: is there a way to create a static dataframe inside mapGroups ? Given that mapGroups gives an Iterator of rows. I just want to take that iterator and populate a static dataframe. is that possible?