# Is it possible to do stateless aggregations using Spark-SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I understand that its possible to do stateless aggregation using `mapGroups` and `flatMapGroups` API in Spark 2.x+. I want to use aggregate queries on a streaming registered temporary view. Is there any way to do the same using `spark.sql(" ... ")` ?

PS: I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189613/how-to-do-stateless-aggregations-in-spark-using-structured-streaming-2-3-0-witho)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define and use a User-Defined Aggregate Function in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100973/how-to-define-and-use-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-spark-sql)